# Docker Scheduling Strategy Clarification

Tags: docker-swarm

I am new to docker, was playing around trying to run multiple containers on a swarm with spread strategy. Swarm had 3 nodes & each node already had 2 containers , and i ran 3 more docker run commands so that each node gets 1 more container.

As I was running docker containers without specifying memory using -m , nor CPU in the docker run command. After doing so i ran "docker info" but i noticed that Reserved memory was 0.
[image]

I re ran container by specifying -m , this time i noticed that Reserved memory is not 0.

**Question is** : when running containers without using -m command , why is the Reserved memory is shown 0 , although the running containers ( spawned without -m ) still would be using memory ... For Example , if there are 10 containers already running on a single node (i.e the host memory would be full) and i try to start a container on same host machine by giving -m 1G it may not have space to reserve ,hence will it fail ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. When you don't specify the reserved memory with `-m` memory is still used.

You see `0` because this is the default when reserved memory is not specified. That number is not the real consumption of memory on the node. So `0` makes sense, as a setting rather than a real time report.

This was discussed on issue [#1819](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1819#issuecomment-184934167) in the docker swarm project.